# unable to get bordertitle below textfield in panel in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, panel, border-layout

I have been writing and refactoring the code that I started with for Hangman game. I have basically two classes now. One is that launch the hangman (contains main) and other is the getting the panel plugged in with various components. In total, I will have one frame and one Panel, few buttons and a Label and textfield. I have pasted my two bits of code below. I wanted to have all the pushed down to the frame, The label and textfield in the center and I need empty space on the top to put more stuff. I tried BorderLayout.SOUTH, but did not help. The border title is spreading all over, but I would like it to have it surround just the radio buttons. Kindly run the code to see what I mean.
Thanks
Code1 : with Main method

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class HangmanGUI {

    DetailsPanel myPanel;

    public HangmanGUI() throws ParseException {

        myPanel = new DetailsPanel();
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
        myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
        myframe.setVisible(true);
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myframe.pack();
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        new HangmanGUI();
    }
}
```

code 2: with panel and components

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {

    public DetailsPanel() {

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" ciick here "));

        createFormattedPanel();

        for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
            String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
            JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
            letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
            this.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

    }

    private ActionListener clickedbutton() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
                System.out.println("actionCommand is: " + actionCommand);
            }
        };
    }

    public void createFormattedPanel() {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("? ? ? ? ? ? ?");
            formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('?');
            JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
            input.setColumns(20);
            this.add(label);
            this.add(input);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an image JPanel to hold your hangman drawing, and to act as a placeholder and place it in the JFrame in the BorderLayout.CENTER position. I would also clean up the south JPanel by using layout managers and not relying on default FlowLayout. For instance a BorderLayout for the south Jpanel, put the guess in the page start slot and the buttons in the center slot, and put the buttons into a GridLayout JPanel. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class HangmanGUI {
   private DetailsPanel myPanel;
   private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

   public HangmanGUI() throws ParseException {
      myPanel = new DetailsPanel();
      JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
      // myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      myframe.getContentPane().add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
      // myframe.setVisible(true);
      // myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      myframe.pack();
      myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      myframe.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      new HangmanGUI();
   }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final String TITLE = "Hangman Image";

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public ImagePanel() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(TITLE));
   }
}

class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {
   public DetailsPanel() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" ciick here "));
      add(createFormattedPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

      JPanel letterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
      for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
         String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
         JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
         letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
         letterPanel.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }
      add(letterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private ActionListener clickedbutton() {
      return new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println("actionCommand is: " + actionCommand);
         }
      };
   }

   public JPanel createFormattedPanel() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      MaskFormatter formatter = null;
      try {
         JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
         formatter = new MaskFormatter("? ? ? ? ? ? ?");
         formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('?');
         JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
         input.setColumns(20);
//         this.add(label);
//         this.add(input);
         panel.add(label);
         panel.add(input);
      } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
         System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      return panel;
   }
}
```

Also, don't set the position of a component or set it visible until after adding all and packing all. Don't set a component's size but rather let the preferred sizes and the layout managers set the sizes for you.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> first of all thank you for helping out. This is the solution I wanted. I have some basic questions though. why did you comment out // myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

The JFrame's contentPane already uses BorderLayout by default so it would be unnecessary to explicitly set it to this layout.

> also you created three panels, which is nice. for imagepanel, you specified the dimension. but for detailsPanel, you did not specify the dimension. does it mean?

I figure that the image will have a definite size, and so I override its getPreferredSize so that it will be big enough to show the image. All other components, I let them size themselves based on their component's preferred sizes and their layout managers.

> if I have many panels and I specify dimension(size) for one panel, all others will get that default on the frame.

Again, all others will have their own preferred sizes based on the preferred sizes of their components and their layout managers.

Comment: first of all thank you for helping out. This is the solution I wanted. I have some basic questions though. why did you comment out `// myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

Comment: also you created three panels, which is nice. for imagepanel, you specified the dimension. but for detailsPanel, you did not specify the dimension. does it mean? if I have many panels and I specify dimension(size) for one panel, all others will get that default on the frame..

Comment: Thank you. I am stuck with something on the next step in this problem, I have pasted it here, if you could kindly look             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439431/how-to-adjust-image-in-a-panel-in-java-swing

Answer (score 2):

"IF" I understand correctly, why not just add the buttons to their own panel and set the title border on it instead, for example...

```
public DetailsPanel() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));

    createFormattedPanel();

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" ciick here "));

    for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
        String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
        JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
        letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
        buttons.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    add(buttons);

}
```

Comment: that means I am having two panels correct? one the DetailsPanel itself and now the panel for buttons? some people suggest to have only panel as a good practice...? is that correct?

Comment: *"some people suggest to have only panel as a good practice"* I'd be surprised to know why.  What you could do is create another custom component with just the buttons in it, allowing you to contain the functionality with in it, but allowing you to re-use the component as you need.  It also allows you to isolate the layout requirements for each section of your component(s)

Comment: @user1988876: I second mad's recommendations. Use multiple JPanels each with their own layout managers. 1+.

Comment: Thank you both! I am a beginner. I am so willing to take good advices and practices. for instance, should I keep all the button components code seperately, and the textfield & label seperately, and just add them to Panel before add panel to frame?

Comment: @user1988876 If I was doing this, I would.  I would also bridge these components with some kind of model and allow the model to drive the UI.  This removes the need for one part of the UI to really know anything else about the rest of the UI, as it's only concern is the model, but that's just me :P

Answer (score 2):

You count create a `GridLayout` for your buttons like so:

```
public DetailsPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    createFormattedPanel();
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" ciick here "));
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,6));

    for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
        String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
        JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
        letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
        buttons.add(letterButton);
    }
    add(buttons);
}
```

Then I also added an extra dummy Panel in your main with just a label, change this label to what ever component you want:

```
    myPanel = new DetailsPanel();
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
    JPanel aDummy = new JPanel();
    aDummy.add(new JLabel("Extra text"));
    myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    myframe.getContentPane().add(aDummy, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //...etc
```

Comes out like this

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping out..even with current code, it produces similar output,I want entire thing to be pushed down. and space on top for other stuff.

Comment: @user1988876 As you add more panels on top (where I have the "Extra Text") It will get pushed down, Thats what I Trying to demostrate

Comment: @user1988876 Also with your code as it was, see what happens when you resize the window then compare it to mine.