# how to adjust image in a panel in Java swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have some bits of code with a lot of help from fellow programmers in SO. First off, Thank you all for that. Now I have this code for hangman. I want the textfield to appear below the image, right now it is shooting on top of it. I have provided the link for the image in the code. but you might need to download it to avoid exception thrown. 
I want to keep top right corner free for timer, which I have not thought how to do yet.
I need assistance in getting image and texfield in correct positions. please execute code to see how it looks currently. I tried both BorderLayout.SOUTH and BorderLayout.PAGE_END, but it did not help Thank you

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class HangmanGUI {
   private DetailsPanel myPanel;
   private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

   public HangmanGUI() throws ParseException {
      myPanel = new DetailsPanel();
      JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
      // myframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      myframe.getContentPane().add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
      // myframe.setVisible(true);
      // myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      myframe.pack();
      myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      myframe.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      new HangmanGUI();
   }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final String TITLE = "Hangman Image";
   private BufferedImage image;

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public ImagePanel() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(TITLE));
      try {
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Hangman-0.png"));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      add(createFormattedPanel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  //add(createFormattedPanel(),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
   }

   public JPanel createFormattedPanel() {
          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          MaskFormatter formatter = null;
          try {
             JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
             formatter = new MaskFormatter("? ? ? ? ? ? ?");
             formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('?');
             JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
             input.setColumns(20);
             panel.add(label);
             panel.add(input);
          } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
             System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
             System.exit(-1);
          }

          return panel;
       }

   }

class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {
   public DetailsPanel() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" click here "));
      //add(createFormattedPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

      JPanel letterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
      for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
         String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
         JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
         letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
         letterPanel.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }
      add(letterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private ActionListener clickedbutton() {
      return new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println("actionCommand is: " + actionCommand);
         }
      };
   }

}
```

Comment: You should also beware that `ImageIO` can read images of `URL` as well as `File` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're mixing custom painting and components into a single component, you are losing control over how your components are laid out.

Two solutions come to mind...

### Use a JLabel

Use a `JLabel` to display the image, placing it in the `CENTER` position of the `ImagePane` and the "formatted panel" in the `SOUTH` position

### Separate your components in logic groups

Split apart your UI so that each component is isolated...

```
-- Hangman Image --------------
| --------------------------- |
| | ----------------------- | |
| | |                     | | |
| | |                     | | |
| | | (Image Pane)        | | |
| | |                     | | |
| | |                     | | |
| | ----------------------- | |
| | ----------------------- | |
| | | Guess: ? ? ? ? ? ?  | | |
| | ----------------------- | |
| --------------------------- |
| -- click here ------------- |
| |                         | |
| |                         | |
| | (buttons   )            | |
| |                         | |
| |                         | |
| --------------------------- |
-------------------------------
```

Basically, the `ImagePane`, the `GuessPane` and the `ClickPane` are all separate components.

You would then add the `ImagePane` and `GuessPane` onto another `JPanel` (using `BorderLayout`) and then add this and the `ClickPane` onto the main panel (using a `BorderLayout`).

This will give you greater control over how the individual components are laid out and can be combined.

== Example Using `JLabel` ==

This is a basic example of using a `JLabel` over using custom painting.

The `ImagePane` and `GuessPane` are added to separate panel, which is added to the `CENTER` position of the frame.  The `DetailsPane` is then added to the `SOUTH` position of the frame...

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class HangmanGUI {

    private DetailsPanel myPanel;

    public HangmanGUI() throws ParseException {
        myPanel = new DetailsPanel();
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(new ImagePane());
        content.add(new GuessPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Hangman Image"));

        myframe.getContentPane().add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myframe.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        myframe.setTitle("Hangman Game");
        myframe.pack();
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                try {
                    new HangmanGUI();
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public ImagePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);
            try {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Hangman-0.png"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                label.setText("Bad Image");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static class GuessPane extends JPanel {

        public GuessPane() {
            MaskFormatter formatter = null;
            try {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Guesss");
                formatter = new MaskFormatter("? ? ? ? ? ? ?");
                formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('?');
                JFormattedTextField input = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
                input.setColumns(20);
                add(label);
                add(input);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
                System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {

        public DetailsPanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" click here "));
            //add(createFormattedPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JPanel letterPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
            for (char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z'; alphabet++) {
                String buttonText = String.valueOf(alphabet);
                JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
                letterButton.addActionListener(clickedbutton());
                letterPanel.add(letterButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            add(letterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private ActionListener clickedbutton() {
            return new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
                    System.out.println("actionCommand is: " + actionCommand);
                }
            };
        }

    }
}
```

This type of separation is going to require to use some kind of model to bridge across the components.

That is, when the user makes a guess, you need to update the model, which will notify the other components (via some kind of listener API) that some change has occurred, this will allow the other UI elements to update themselves as required to meet the requirements of the  model.

The model should contain the logic for the game and drive the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will implement the way you mentioned.`Use a JLabel to display the image, placing it in the CENTER position of the ImagePane and the "formatted panel" in the SOUTH position`-- what you mean here

Comment: The problem is, as far as the `BorderLayout` is concerned, it's laid out the panel correctly.  If you add a `JLabel` to the center position and use it's `icon` capabilities to draw the image, it will push the panel with the formatted field (guess) to the bottom where you expect it.  It's "similar" to the second option, but just takes a little less work...

Comment: so do I have to have `new Dimension(xxx,yyy)` for each of the `ImagePane, GuessPane and the Holderpane` for these two besides one for `ClickPane`

Comment: Personally, I would avoid it.  `JLabel` will automatically want to use the size of the image as it's preferred size any way...

Comment: so `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(PicURL)); JLabel img = new JLabel(); img.setIcon(icon);` I tried this and it seems to work with local copy of image. but if i give `http`url it does not work. does `JLabel` icon not work with web urls..?

Comment: `ImageIcon` will take a `URL` class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39457/discussion-between-user1988876-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: may I know why made the `GuessPane` and `DetailsPane` class static?

Comment: Because I've made the  inner classes. This is done purely for simplicity of the example, as you can paste the entire code sample into a single file and run it ;)

Comment: I have been working on HangMan Model example that you provided. If I want to give the option of replaying the game (yes or No), after the JOptionPane pops up, how can I do that? should this be a part of HangManPane. I need your help here

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me, but it may not matter. You'd could attach a listener to the model and when a win/lose event occurs, you could popup a JOptionPane. If they select yes, create a new model and apply it to the top level game panel...but yes, you could make it part of the main game panel if that was easier